# Why am I getting the error "Cannot instantiate implementation type" for my generic service?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a generic repository that I have been instantiating right in my WEB API Controller no problem for a while.

This is what my controller used to look like:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class EmployeesController : Controller
{
    private IGenericRepository<Employee> _empRepo;

    public EmployeesController(IGenericRepository<Employee> employeeRepo)
    {
        _empRepo = employeeRepo;
    }

    // GET: api/employees
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Employee>> GetEmployeesAsync(
            string firstName = null, string lastName = null)
    {
        //return await _empRepo.GetAll().Include("Organization").Include("PayPlan").Include("GradeRank").Include("PositionTitle").Include("Series").Include("BargainingUnit")
        //    .Where(e => (string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstName) || e.FirstName.Contains(firstName))
        //        && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastName) || e.LastName.Contains(lastName))
        //    )
        //    .ToListAsync();

        return await _empRepo.GetAllIncluding(
                a => a.Organization,
                b => b.PayPlan,
                c => c.GradeRank,
                d => d.PositionTitle,
                e => e.Series,
                f => f.BargainingUnit)
            .Where(e => (string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstName) || e.FirstName.Contains(firstName))
                && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastName) || e.LastName.Contains(lastName))
            )
            .ToListAsync();
    }

    // GET api/employees/5
    [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetEmployeeById")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetEmployeeByIdAsync(long id)
    {         
        //var employee = await _empRepo.Find(id).Include("Organization").Include("PayPlan").Include("GradeRank").Include("PositionTitle").Include("Series").Include("BargainingUnit").SingleAsync();
        var employee = await  _empRepo.GetSingleIncludingAsync(id,
            a => a.Organization,
            b => b.PayPlan,
            c => c.GradeRank, 
            d => d.PositionTitle,
            e => e.Series,
            f => f.BargainingUnit);

        if (employee == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        else
        {
            return new ObjectResult(employee);
        }
    }

    // PUT api/employees/id
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PutEmployeeAsync([FromBody] Employee emp)
    {
        var employee = await _empRepo.UpdateAsync(emp);
        if (employee == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        await _empRepo.SaveAsync();
        return new ObjectResult(employee);
    }
}
```

and we would configure the DI in StartUp like this:

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(IGenericRepository<>), typeof(GenericRepository<>));
```

Now I have just refactored and tried to put a service layer in between the controller and the generic repo.

So here is my second DI line in StartUp:

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(IGenericService<>), typeof(IGenericService<>));
```

So now I have these two DI lines:

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(IGenericRepository<>), typeof(GenericRepository<>));
services.AddScoped(typeof(IGenericService<>), typeof(IGenericService<>));
```

The following is my current code:

Starting with the Generic Repo:

```
public enum FilteredSource
{
    All,
    GetAllIncluding,
}

public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T>
    where T: BaseEntity
{
    protected readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    protected DbSet<T> _dbSet;

    public GenericRepository(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        _dbSet = context.Set<T>();
    }

    // no eager loading
    private IQueryable<T> All => _dbSet.Cast<T>();

    #region FIXME : DELETE
    // FIXME: Delete and use ALL instead.
    public IQueryable<T> GetAll() => _dbSet.AsQueryable();

    // FIXME: Delete and use GetSingleIncludingAsync instead.
    public IQueryable<T> Find(long id) =>
        _dbSet.Where(e => e.Id == id).AsQueryable();
    #endregion

    // eager loading
    private IQueryable<T> GetAllIncluding(
        params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties) =>
         includeProperties.Aggregate(All, (currentEntity, includeProperty) => currentEntity.Include(includeProperty));

    // no eager loading
    public async Task<T> GetSingleIncludingAsync(long id)
    {
        return await _dbSet.SingleOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Id == id);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Takes in a lambda selector and let's you filter results from GetAllIncluding and All.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="selector">labmda expression to filter results by.</param>
    /// <param name="getFilteredSource">All or GetAllIncluding as the method to get results from.</param>
    /// <param name="includeProperties">array of eager load lamda expressions.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetFiltered(
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> selector, FilteredSource filteredSource,
        Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties = null)
    {
        var results = default(IEnumerable<T>);
        switch (filteredSource)
        {
            case FilteredSource.All:
                results = All.Where(selector);
                break;
            case FilteredSource.GetAllIncluding:
                results = GetAllIncluding(includeProperties).Where(selector);
                break;
        }
        return await results.AsQueryable().ToListAsync();
    }

    // eager loading
    public async Task<T> GetSingleIncludingAsync(
        long id, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties)
    {
        IQueryable<T> entities = GetAllIncluding(includeProperties);
        //return await Filter<long>(entities, x => x.Id, id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        return await entities.SingleOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Id == id);
    }

    public async Task<T> InsertAsync(T entity)
    {
        if (entity == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException($"No {nameof(T)}  Entity was provided for Insert");
        }
        await _dbSet.AddAsync(entity);
        return entity;
    }

    public async Task<T> UpdateAsync(T entity)
    {
        T entityToUpdate = await
            _dbSet.AsNoTracking().SingleOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Id == entity.Id);
        if (entityToUpdate == null)
        {
            //return null;
            throw new ArgumentNullException($"No {nameof(T)}  Entity was provided for Update");
        }

        _dbSet.Update(entity);
        return entity;
    }

    public async Task<T> DeleteAsync(T entity)
    {
        _dbSet.Remove(entity);
        return await Task.FromResult(entity);
    }

    public Task SaveAsync() => _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Interface Definition:

```
public interface IGenericRepository<T>
    where T : BaseEntity
{
    #region FIXME : DELETE
    // FIXME: Delete and use ALL instead.
    IQueryable<T> GetAll();

    // FIXME: Delete and use GetSingleIncludingAsync instead.
    IQueryable<T> Find(long id);
    #endregion

    // eager loading
    Task<T> GetSingleIncludingAsync(
        long id, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties);

    Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetFiltered(
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> selector, FilteredSource filteredSource,
        Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties = null);

    Task<T> InsertAsync(T entity);
    Task<T> UpdateAsync(T entity);
    Task<T> DeleteAsync(T entity);

    #region Possible TODOs:
    //Task<IEnumerable<T>> FindBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
    //Task AddRange(IEnumerable<T> entities);
    //Task RemoveRange(IEnumerable<T> entities);
    #endregion

    Task SaveAsync();
}
```

This gets injected into my Generic Service:

```
public class GenericService<T> : IGenericService<T>
    where T : BaseEntity
{
    private IGenericRepository<T> _genericRepo;

    public GenericService(IGenericRepository<T> genericRepo)
    {
        _genericRepo = genericRepo;
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetFiltered(
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> selector, FilteredSource filteredSource,
        Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties = null)
    {
        return await _genericRepo.GetFiltered(selector, filteredSource,
            includeProperties);
    }

    // eager loading
    public async Task<T> GetSingleIncludingAsync(long id, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties)
    {
        IEnumerable<T> entities = await _genericRepo.GetFiltered(null, FilteredSource.GetAllIncluding, includeProperties);
        //return await Filter<long>(entities, x => x.Id, id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        return entities.SingleOrDefault(e => e.Id == id);
    }

    public async Task<T> InsertAsync(T entity)
    {
        var result = await _genericRepo.InsertAsync(entity);
        await _genericRepo.SaveAsync();
        return entity;
    }

    public async Task<T> UpdateAsync(T entity)
    {
        var result = await _genericRepo.UpdateAsync(entity);
        if (result != null)
        {
            await _genericRepo.SaveAsync();
        }
        return result;
    }

    public async Task<T> DeleteAsync(T entity)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Interface Definition for the Service:

```
public interface IGenericService<T>
    where T : BaseEntity
{
    Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetFiltered(
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> selector, FilteredSource filteredSource,
        Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties = null);

    // eager loading
    Task<T> GetSingleIncludingAsync(long id, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties);

    Task<T> InsertAsync(T entity);
    Task<T> UpdateAsync(T entity);
    Task<T> DeleteAsync(T entity);
}
```

and finally, here is the controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class EmployeesController : Controller
{
    private IGenericService<Employee> _genericService;

    public EmployeesController(IGenericService<Employee> genericService)
    {
        _genericService = genericService;
    }

    // GET: api/employees
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Employee>> GetEmployeesAsync(
            string firstName = null, string lastName = null)
    {
        return await _genericService.GetFiltered(
                e => (string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstName) || e.FirstName.Contains(firstName))
                && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastName) || e.LastName.Contains(lastName)),
                FilteredSource.GetAllIncluding,
                new Expression<Func<Employee, object>>[] { a => a.Organization,
                b => b.PayPlan,
                c => c.GradeRank,
                d => d.PositionTitle,
                e => e.Series,
                f => f.BargainingUnit }
            );
    }

    // GET api/employees/5
    [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetEmployeeById")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetEmployeeByIdAsync(long id)
    {
        //var employee = await _empRepo.Find(id).Include("Organization").Include("PayPlan").Include("GradeRank").Include("PositionTitle").Include("Series").Include("BargainingUnit").SingleAsync();
        var employee = await _genericService.GetSingleIncludingAsync(id,
            a => a.Organization,
            b => b.PayPlan,
            c => c.GradeRank,
            d => d.PositionTitle,
            e => e.Series,
            f => f.BargainingUnit);

        if (employee == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        else
        {
            return new ObjectResult(employee);
        }
    }

    // PUT api/employees/id
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PutEmployeeAsync([FromBody] Employee emp)
    {
        var employee = await _genericService.UpdateAsync(emp);
        if (employee == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return new ObjectResult(employee);
    }
}
```

I'm just not sure how to plug in the middle service layer.

Answer (score 157):

This happened to me recently. I had the implementation class marked "abstract", an artifact of an earlier design. I removed it and the container was able to instantiate the class without a problem.

Comment: This also was my case.

Comment: Te Allam. kim yazdı lan class ın başına abstract diye. rezil olduk.

Answer (score 127):

I'm an idiot.
I had the Inteface for the implementation.
I changed:

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(IGenericService<>), typeof(IGenericService<>));
```

to

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(IGenericService<>), typeof(GenericService<>));
```

Comment: Same mistake. I was using an alias and thought that caused the error, e.g. `using shortName= Foo.Repository.Repositories.Contacts;` That was actually fine, and the problem was mixing up interface/implementation order.

Comment: I added an abstract implementation class. How is this so popular mistake

Comment: This happened to me just now, this comment helper me fix it! :)

Comment: I am also an idiot - I have been doing so much wiring today it all got too blurry. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: This is because Visual Studio IntelliSense autocomplete does so, easy to oversight

Answer (score 14):

Great question and great answers so far, however...

#### If your problem is different but the error message is the same

...and you are registering the service for a default implementation, **without specifying the implementation type**, like here:

```
services.AddScoped<IMyDependency>();
```

Then the error is unhelpful because it does not give details on **why** things don't work:

> Cannot instantiate implementation type 'MyApp.IMyDependency' for service type 'MyApp.IMyDependency'.

In that case, change the service registration to:

```
services.AddScoped<IMyDependency, MyDependency>();
```

**That will improve the error message and it will tell you where is the problem**, like so:

> Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: MyApp.IMyDependency Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: MyApp.MyDependency': **Unable to resolve service for type 'MyApp.ILowerDependency'** while attempting to activate 'MyApp.IMyDependency'.)

In the default ASP.NET core DI container, entire dependency graph needs to be registered explicitly (*except maybe for some exceptions like ILogger*)

Comment: You read my mind. For me, it was enough to add the concrete type to the service registration.

Answer (score 6):

Following on Bartosz answer, another reason for this message is if you are trying to satisfy a non-generic interface with a generic concrete type like this:

`services.AddScoped(typeof(IMyDependency), typeof(MyDependency<,>));`

This won't work because the DI container doesn't know what generic arguments to provide when instantiating MyDependency. Either the interface has to be converted to generic or you need a factory to instantiate it manually.

Answer (score 5):

Based on David's answer, I had to remove the 'abstract' in my service implementation class. However I had some **abstract methods and properties** in the class too. So after making them non-abstract and creating a **public constructor** I was able to register the service.

Comment: this is the answer. crazy how basic things takes hours to find out why it doesnt work :D

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me when ***service*** class didn't inherit from ***IService***
 interface

Answer (score 2):

This seems obvious now that I've figured it out, but if you are doing assembly scanning registrations, you'll want to exclude your abstract classes and interfaces:

```
var assembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load("My.Namespace");
if (assembly == null)
    return;

var types = assembly.GetTypes().Where(x => x?.Namespace != null &&
                                           x.Namespace.Contains("My.Namespace.ViewModels") &&
                                           x.Name.Contains("ViewModel") &&
                                           !x.Name.Contains(nameof(MyAbstractViewModelBase)) &&
                                           !x.Name.Contains(nameof(IMyAbstractViewModel)));

foreach (var thing in types)
    services.AddScoped(thing);
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was attempting to inject the config without an instance... face palm. Changing

```
services.AddSingleton<IOptions<AzureBlobConfiguration>>();
```

to

```
builder.Services.AddOptions<AzureBlobConfiguration>()
    .Bind(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureBlobConfiguration"))
    .ValidateOnStart();
```

fixed it for me.

Answer (score -1):

```
builder.Services.AddTransient<Istudent , StudentService>();
```

Where the implementation of the `Istudent` interface is done in the `StudentService` class.