# Dotnetcore 2.2 application fails to start

Tags: asp.net-core

I started a new project using `dotnet new mvc` and the first thing I did was to to generate models to my database using `dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold(...)`. I basically followed the instructions I got from -> https://www.mydatahack.com/creating-web-apis-using-asp-net-and-mysql-in-5-minutes/.

Everything builds but when application tries to run I get the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Configuration value 'False' is not supported.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerFilterConfigureOptions.TryGetSwitch(String value, LogLevel& level)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerFilterConfigureOptions.LoadRules(LoggerFilterOptions options, IConfigurationSection configurationSection, String logger)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerFilterConfigureOptions.LoadDefaultConfigValues(LoggerFilterOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerFilterConfigureOptions.Configure(LoggerFilterOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory`1.Create(String name)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor`1.<>c__DisplayClass10_0.<Get>b__0()
   at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
   at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsCache`1.GetOrAdd(String name, Func`1 createOptions)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor`1.Get(String name)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor`1.get_CurrentValue()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerFactory..ctor(IEnumerable`1 providers, IOptionsMonitor`1 filterOption)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitSingleton(SingletonCallSite singletonCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitSingleton(SingletonCallSite singletonCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.Build()
   at Negotium.Program.Main(String[] args) in Program.cs:line 18
```

The dotnet core sdk version is 2.2.103 running on Fedora 29

Not sure if this will be any help at all but here is my .csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
  </PropertyGroup>


  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="log4net" Version="2.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.2.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.2.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.2.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.2.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design" Version="1.1.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.2.1">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.2.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.15" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

And below is the startup.cs file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Extensions;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Negotium.Models;

namespace Negotium
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            services.AddDbContext<NegotiumContext>(options =>
                options.UseMySQL(Configuration.GetConnectionString("NegotiumDatabase")));

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();


            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace Negotium
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();


        }
        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
                        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you share Starup.cs with us?

Comment: Hi, I included the startup.cs in the question

Comment: Can you also share your Program.cs?

Comment: Hi, I have included it in the question above.

Comment: @Louxid as the stack trace shows, there is some value `False` in your configuration, which is not allowed. Might be expecting `false`, lower case `f`. You can try pasting your config here or try it out yourself.

Comment: Hi @inthevortex I have went through the appsettings.json, appsettings.Development.json, .csproj, launchsetting.json, Program.cs and startup.cs and I have not found ```False``` written in this way.

Comment: @Louxid i see, did you check out the things in Simonare's answer?

Comment: Is there any demo or details steps to reproduce your issue?

Comment: @TaoZhou, I started a new project as mentioned above, created mysql database and then followed the instructions from https://www.mydatahack.com/creating-web-apis-using-asp-net-and-mysql-in-5-minutes/.

Comment: I never found a solution to the problem but I started a new project and followed the same procedure and I don't have any issues anymore. Thank you all for the efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Generally Default Configuration Providers are :

- ChainedConfigurationProvider
- JsonConfigurationProvider
- JsonConfigurationProvider (Development)
- Secret Manager
- EnvironmentVariablesConfigurationProvider
- CommandLineConfigurationProvider

Check each provider for erroneous `False` vaue.

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#default-configuration)

Answer (score 0):

I see that the OP never found an actual solution to his problem and I had this same issue just recently. My solution [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63636321/5543032) to another question is quite simple and may help others stumbling upon this post.

If my solution doesn't work for you, the question I posted it to has tons of other solutions. Although the question is different, I believe it stems from the same issue.