# HTTP Error 500.32 - ANCM Failed to Load dll after deploying a Self Contained .Net Core 3.1 App to Azure

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core

I have an Asp .NET Core 3.1 App which is deployed to Azure App Service (West Europe/Windows based). When I use a Framework dependendant Deployment Mode, the app is starting smoothly.

But, when I try to switch to a Self Contained deployment, the App fails to start and I get an error message : *HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure*

Changing the Runtime from win-x86 to x64 didn't solve the problem.

I inspected the App Server runtime versions installed and it looks like runtimes are available (cf. screenshot below).

What am I doing wrong?

[image: Server Installed Runtimes]

Comment: Double check your `Startup.cs` and/or `Program.cs` files https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/8980

Comment: @rak007 this is not the issue, I have no dual registration and it works perfectly fine on my local machine.

Answer (score 16):

For .net 5 the issue is the same I had to remove the hostingModel="inprocess" from the web.config so it read the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
 <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
  <system.webServer>
   <handlers>
    <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
   </handlers>
   <aspNetCore processPath=".\Hub.WebApi.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout"  />
 </system.webServer>
</location>
</configuration>
```

**Edit 07/12/22**

The same is true for **.net 7** as found out on a new site.
You will see here **.net 7** and in the csproject I placed AspNetCoreHostingModel and the value OutOfProcess this means when you publish it will always be ok no more editing web.config after.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

<PropertyGroup>
<TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
<Nullable>enable</Nullable>
<ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  <AspNetCoreHostingModel>OutOfProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>

 </PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 9):

In case the above does not resolve your issue, and in case you missed it within https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/8980, but this solved my issue.

Per DimaSUN commented on Jun 25, 2019:

ASP.NET Core 2.2 or later: For a 64-bit (x64) self-contained deployment that uses the in-process hosting model, disable the app pool for 32-bit (x86) processes.

How to: 
Open Application Pool within IIS. Select the website > Advanced Settings.
Set 32-bit Applications from True to False.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding .Net Core 3.1 extension in your app service? Development Tools -> Extensions -> Add -> Asp.Net Core 3.1 with the runtime you require.

I had the same issue yesterday and after adding the extension, the problem was gone.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Unfortunately I tried adding the extension and now I get an HTTP 403 --> the server doesn't start at all. Any idea where does this come from?

Answer (score 1):

In the event it helps anyone else...  I still had `UseKestrel()` in my `Program.cs` (which makes sense given that [others mentioned the hosting model as the culprit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59390437)).

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => {
            webBuilder.UseKestrel(k => k.AddServerHeader = false);
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
```

Removing Kestrel (naturally) alleviates the problem.

I also eventually saw this in the [Kudu Debug Console](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/troubleshoot-azure-iis?view=aspnetcore-2.2#application-event-log-azure-app-service-1)...

> Application is running inside IIS process but is not configured to use
>   IIS server

Answer (score 1):

Completely *unrelated* to the troubleshooting tips this error provides, this can also be caused by insufficient permissions of the app pool account on the *source directory* of the `.NET Core` application.

When the service account only had *Read permissions* I got this error. After adding *Read & Execute permissions* (since the application is an `.exe`) the error went away.