# HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure in .net core 2.2

Tags: rest, api, .net-core

I am trying to run this REST API and I keep getting the follwing error:

```
HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure
```

I tried to upgrade .net core to 2.2.5 from 2.2.0 . 2.2.0 was default version with Visual studio. I am coding this in Visual studio 2019.

I also downloaded dotnet hosting bundle from the below web site:

```
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2
```

I downloaded the V2.2.5 version and installed SDK, ASP.NET Core Runtime 2.2.5 and .NET Core Runtime 2.2.5 for windows X64.

below is the screen shot.

[image]

and below is the screenshot of my dotnet info:

[image]

Despite of downloading everything, I kept getting an error :

```
HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure
```

Finally, I changed my csproj file AspNetCoreHostingModel to outofprocesss and then the error changed to
 process failure so I changed the csproj back to original file.

Currently, my csproj file looks like below:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>

  <AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>

  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.2.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.2.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design" Version="1.1.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.2.6">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.2.4" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Update="Microsoft.NETCore.App" Version="2.2.5" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

My statrtup.cs file looks like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using RecLoadAPI.Models.DB;
namespace RecLoadAPI
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors();
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
            services.AddDbContext<db_recloadContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            // app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried to follow this link, but still getting the same error:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53811569/http-error-500-30-ancm-in-process-start-failure
```

any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you host your application within IIS.  I suggest starting your application directly via Kestrel without IIS (dotnet "path_to_your_executable_dll" or simply "path_to_you_executable_exe"). If the application starts correctly, the problem is about IIS (ASP_NET Core Module, etc. - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/troubleshoot-azure-iis?view=aspnetcore-2.2#50030-in-process-startup-failure). If the error persists, you probably get additional output.

Comment: 2.2 is end-of-life, so you shouldn't use it any more. Once you switch to a supported version and can reproduce this issue, run some basic diagnostics and edit your question to include that, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html