# Azure App Service - HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

I have a .NET Core 3.0.100 Azure App Service, which is deployed via Azure Pipelines.

Very intermittently (I mean once every 50 days).... we get a 500

'HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure'

Then I'll redeploy the exact same package and it works again. We get this same issue in production so I need to get it resolved.

Azure support have advised to set stdoutLogEnabled to true in our web.config next time it occurs.

Is there something more pro-active I can do at this time to find out what the issue is ahead of it occurring again?

As I mentioned it just fixes itself after a subsequent re-deploy so I fail to see what could be wrong on my end.

Thanking you
Andrew Duffy

Comment: More proactive? Maybe switch to Linux/Docker on Azure App Service, so that IIS module won't even be in your way.

Comment: I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53811569/http-error-500-30-ancm-in-process-start-failure) which suggests changing InProcess to OutOfProcess.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there is an issue o [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/8980) for this. For some people it was issue wich registering dependencies and for some connection string format. Did you try already to check this topic and verify how it is in your app? Sorry but without more details it is really difficult to say sth more as it can be (and probably it is) related to application itself.