# HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure - Production Environment

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I was configuring my application for deployment. The first step I did was changing the environment from Development to Production and stumbled in this error. I noticed that I can launch my application only in the Development Environment. When I change them to Staging, Production I get the mentioned error. Also, I tried the solutions from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53811569/http-error-500-30-ancm-in-process-start-failure), and still no success.

Here are the related configurations:

**launchSettings.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:64845",
      "sslPort": 44375
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production"
      }
    },
    "BingoAPI": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**xx.csproj**

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: You might need to share your Startup.cs and your Program.cs in addition to web.config and full project file

Comment: If you want to set your `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` to **production** state, you can just remove `environmentVariables` from your `launchSettings.json`. 
Read [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: I noticed the application can run with the Production environment on the server. I guess then it's some operating system related stuff so I will leave it like that