# HTTP Error 500.30 - ASP.NET Core app failed to start

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, deployment, publish

I deploy a .NET Core app with settings:
[image]

And the website shows an error:

> HTTP Error 500.30 - ASP.NET Core app failed to start
> Common solutions
> to this issue:
>
> - The app failed to start
> - The app started but then stopped
> - The app started but threw an exception during startup
>
> Troubleshooting steps:
>
> - Check the system event log for error messages
> - Enable logging the application process' stdout messages
> - Attach a debugger to the application process and inspect
>
> For more information visit:
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=2028265

What is causing this error?

Answer (score 91):

There may be a few reasons behind the error which you can only identify by debugging. You can try to debug this error using the steps below:

1. Navigate to the root directory of the application using CMD
2. Run the application using the command `dotnet run (yourApplicationName).dll`

If there are any errors, they should appear in the output.

Alternatively, you can check "Event Viewer" (search Event Viewer using Windows search) and navigate to

- Windows Logs

  - Application

**Update:**

```
dotnet (yourApplicationName).dll
```

and check http://localhost:5000/ for error

Answer (score 90):

[image]

Go there, and try to manually start your project... i.e.

```
dotnet ServerApp.dll
```

[image]

Comment: This helped me find he root cause of the issue. In my case my connection string was incorrect and app was unable to connect to database at the start of application.

Comment: Any chance you could share the command?

Comment: you can navigate to the logfiles directory: type cd ../../logfiles (assuming you started in c:/home/site/wwwroot. then enter this command: "type eventlog.xml" - assuming this file is in the logfiles folder (which it should be if you are getting a 500.30. (fwiw my web api was looking for a specific folder that did not exist)

Comment: Where is "there" in "go there"? A website? A local location?

Comment: Well that depends. In azure you can go to the specific app sevice, and one of the side tabs would be that one. This is very old though, so it may look a bit different. If it's on a vm, just browse where the service is and do the same

Answer (score 24):

open **Windows Event Viewer**, find the error message and click it, open the **Detail** tab, you will see the exception.

Comment: Event Viewer helped a lot. I was able to see that "System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile' is denied." then I simply browsed to that folder in Explorer and gave myself access

Answer (score 12):

I recently encountered this issue deploying my .net core 5 app to IIS.  I am using environment variables for my various envrionments and the web.config that was deployed was missing the  xml tags.

Changing this line:

```
<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\<your>.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess"/>
```

to:

```
<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\<your>.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess">
   <environmentVariables>
        <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Local" />
   </environmentVariables>
</aspNetCore>
```

This fixed my 500.30 issue.

I took guidance from @Mohammed https://stackoverflow.com/a/59390437/6155498

Answer (score 8):

I had this error running the application on local IIS in windows 10, then I gave full control permission to IIS_IUSRS for App_Data and Logs folders so it worked.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I solved this issue by taking the following steps:

1. Go to "Windows search"
2. search "Event viewer" and open the application
3. Search under the folder "Windows Logs" > "Application"
4. Check the "Error" level warnings

This should identify your error, you should now take steps to take the appropriate actions. In my case, I had the error of "System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException".

This error arose due to my application not having the rights to access an external sever.

I went back to my "Application Pool" settings, changed my "application pool **Identity**" to a user which did have access rights to the server, restarted my application and viola!

All works well.

This is my experience of this error. As said in an earlier post, this error has many remedies depending on the underlying issue

Answer (score 6):

I got the error using Azure App Service

> HTTP Error 500.30 - ASP.NET Core app failed to start

The documentation and App Service logs did not get me anywhere.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/test/troubleshoot-azure-iis?view=aspnetcore-6.0#50030-in-process-startup-failure

I then logged on to the database and checked `Firewalls and virtual networks` and saw that `Allow Azure services and resources to access this server` was set to No. Switching `Allow Azure services and resources to access this server` to Yes solved the error.

[image]

A good place to check is also Azure App Service - Diagnose and solve problems. Another problem I had could be solved using Application Event Logs.

[image]

In this case it was the error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Couldn't find a valid certificate
> with subject 'CN=certificate' on the 'CurrentUser\My'

Turned out I had a expired certificate, renewed and everything worked.

Answer (score 5):

This is a very vague error message, there can be 100s of different reasons behind it. Check your server error logs.

**In my case** Redeploying the application targeting the 64-bit platform fixed the issue.

Answer (score 4):

When the top two answers didn't immediately resolve this error, I started down a deep road of depression wondering "what happened to the azure point, click, done experience I've enjoyed for over 10 years?". And began randomly clicking around the app service page, grasping without hope.

As a last chance (it's always the last chance, isn't it?) I clicked on the "Diagnose and solve problems" link. I had gone down this road before and thought it on only had alert-related stuff.

And then I saw the "Genie" link. "Omg I am so done with the failed promise of chat bots!" I scroamed (screamed and groaned) silently and clicked the link, eyes closed.

And got this...

[image]

I had initially wanted to self-host and had been using (minimal api template) "builer.WebHost.UseKestrel". Commented it out and good to go.

Answer (score 3):

Check whether the attribute value of hostingModel in the configuration file is OutOfProcess. If the value of the hostingModel property is InProcess, try to change it to OutOfProcess and start the project again.

Comment: this is my .csjproj PropertyGroup
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <DocumentationFile>ManToc.Api.xml</DocumentationFile>
    <NoWarn>1701;1702;1591</NoWarn>
    <UserSecretsId>07acd440-eb4a-416e-b906-90c692d326b3</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>

Comment: You can refer to this link to set the value of the hostingModel property: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/out-of-process-hosting?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: You may also have to delete the _web.config_ file in the app service and republish the site so that web.config actually changes.

Answer (score 3):

Ran into this problem today (**NET 5** app, **win-x64** target runtime). I managed to fix it by disabling 32-bit applications support in the IIS Application Pool (see screenshot below):

[image: IIS Application Pool configuration]

As soon as I've switched from *Enable 32-Bit Applications*: *true* to *false*, the HTTP Error 500.30 disappeared.

For additional info, see [this post](https://www.ryadel.com/en/http-error-500-30-asp-net-core-app-failed-to-start-solution/) on my blog.

Answer (score 3):

I also encountered this bug.
With the difference that the target framework of my program is .NET 6.

The mistake I made was not to put the `app.Run()` command in the `Program.cs`.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this error, using this information,

> this issue is mainly with the appsettings.json, the error is caused by the unwanted character in the appsettings.json. To find out exactly what the cause of the HTTP Error 500.30 is, start an application called EventViewer and navigate to System Events. You will be able to see an Event Log of IIS and the main cause of an Error.

sources : [https://www.ernestech.com/articles/details/6899/http-error-500.30---aspnet-core-app-failed-to-start#:~:text=but%20then%20stopped-,Answer%3A%20To%20be%20able%20to%20troubleshoot%20this%20issue%20is%20mainly,and%20navigate%20to%20System%20Events](https://www.ernestech.com/articles/details/6899/http-error-500.30---aspnet-core-app-failed-to-start#:%7E:text=but%20then%20stopped-,Answer%3A%20To%20be%20able%20to%20troubleshoot%20this%20issue%20is%20mainly,and%20navigate%20to%20System%20Events).

turns out I had given a wrong path in `appsettings.json` with too many slashes ////.

Answer (score 2):

This may happen, when something is wrong with Startup.cs file.
For instance it can be placing interface instead of realization class

```
services.AddScoped<IService, IService>();
```

When you need to specify realization class:

```
services.AddScoped<IService, Service>();
```

Answer (score 2):

I have .Net 6 application
I was getting this issue because I had some errors in Dependency Injection. Best way would be to put the try catch over your `CreateWebHostBuilder` in Program.cs, either throw the error or Log it anywhere or put a debugger.

I was missing some dependency mapping.

**Use this way to find the error:**

```
            try
            {
                Log.Information("Starting Service");
                CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
                return 0;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Fatal(ex, "Terminated");
                return 1;
            }
```

Comment: This helped me resolve a application that was failing to start up due to some missing appSettings configuration. Thanks.

Comment: Starting from .Net Core 3, you should use `IHostBuilder` instead of `IWebHostBuilder`

Answer (score 2):

I had a project running on Digital Ocean. After a year, I needed to port that project which was running fine on my local Mac and the Digital Ocean to azure. Then I got the 500.30 error I had tried all of the above but with no luck. Finally, in my case, it was that for my project to work with the Digital Ocean I had to make it work in port 8080, I was using the code below to do that.

```
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.Run();
}
else
{
    app.Run("http://0.0.0.0:8080");
}
```

when at the end delete that code and kept only

```
app.Run()
```

everything works just fine. The same is true if you want to deploy the app in IIS.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you need to refresh the application pool in combination with one of the aforementioned solutions.

Answer (score 1):

- Most often, this issue is caused by a faulty dependency injection in one of your classes.
- Ensure your interfaces are registered in your startup class properly.
- Also check your Logger interfaces you inject in your classes, those could cause issues sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was `UseResponseCompression` which was causing HTTP 500.30.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/response-compression?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Answer (score 0):

On my end, I found that on Azure, I accidentally chose .NET Core 3.1, whereas I was deploying an app targeting ASP.NET Core 5.0. After changing the version to .NET 5.0 on the Azure App Service, it works.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to fix this issue. If your project is inside of a folder that has been renamed or moved, that
means you need to change the folder and drive for that route. If your project is in the drive d:\, leave that and make a new folder in another drive like e:\ or c:\ and test it again.

Comment: Please use proper spelling and punctuation when posting on this site.

Comment: I’ve made a best effort to clarify the instructions here. I’m not confident that I understood the intent, though, so please review and confirm. This is my area of expertise, yet I’m not entirely clear how this guidance relates to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This error message also comes when you try to install the published package to the ISP-hosted shared IIS server or an ISP-hosted Virtual Machine.

- Deployment mode: Framework-Dependent
- Target Runtime: Win-x64 or    Portable

In my case, when I tried to deploy ASP.NET Core 5 application, it occurred due to not setting the change (read/write/delete) permission to the web application folder for the user group, basically the root folder.

Comment: How did you give the permission exatly? Publishing it self contained?

Comment: @AsIndeed, yes I gave them permission to the app. Regarding the next question "Publishing it self-contained?" the answer is above on my answer, read the answer carefully. It is "Framework-Dependent" not "self-contained". Actually, I did not try with "self-contained" deployment mode.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change deployment mode into self contained

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

if your host bundle is 5 and also your app is 5
or
your host bundle is 6 and aslo your app is 6

(for check host version :

NetCoreVersion=@Environment.Version

)

then, set this in your publish setting befr publish:

(Deployment mode: self-contained &
Target Runtime: Win-x64 or Portable)
this option added ~75MB~ necessary files to your published project

Answer (score 0):

Another possible reason: The app throws an exception at startup, e.g. in a static initializer or the like. In that case, the eventlog does not always show any related entries at all, but the console output will tell.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when deploying a site which had been upgraded from dotnet core 3.1 to dotnet 6. Running @uvylight's suggestion revealed that it was complaining about a DLL dependency, and upon investigation the (standard Microsoft) DLL in question had not been updated.

In my case the solution was to change the "Delete existing files" option (in the VS Publish dialogue) to true, which forced it to clear the entire folder on the target server & recopy everything. This took dramatically longer than usual - 17 minutes instead of the usual 1-minute-or-so - but it did the trick, installing the newer versions of all the standard DLLs and resolving the problem. I recommend unticking "Delete existing files" afterwards though.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was throwing an exception when loading the startup file due to mismatching version of one DLL file.

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.

To get the actual exception and stacktrace, you can set the `stdoutLogEnabled` to `true` in `web.config` file, which will log the exceptions in log file and then you can check actual exception.

You can set the `stdoutLogEnabled` to `false` after you resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

When updating from net6 to net8 I got the 500.30 error on publish.

Then I check the box "Remove addicitonal files at destination" and it worked.

[image: Visual Studio 2022 publish dialog]

Answer (score 0):

This generic error message corresponds to an unhandled exception in your startup code and can mean almost anything, so you'll need to dig deeper for the error detail. One way to do this is to simply add a try/catch around your entire startup code in `Program.cs` that logs the error detail to the app log if configured:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        // CreateBuilder, etc.
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Fatal(ex, "Unhandled exception in application startup: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Then redeploy your code and check the log for the exception detail. You'll still get the `500.30` error in the browser, but now you can check the log to know *why* you're getting the error. This will show the error detail even if the system event log doesn't. You can also extend it to show the inner exception if necessary.

Answer (score -1):

Struggled with this for a bit.
Had some start-up code that relied on information in my config files and I did not set an environment variable in my Azure App Service.

Once I sorted that out all was well.

Answer (score -1):

I was getting this same error and none of the answers helped me.  My scenario was I had multiple sites setup on the server and i had set my WebAPI Core 6 app to run on port 8080 in the bindings.  The problem was i had not allowed that port through the firewall on the server.  I hope this helps someone else so you dont waste hours on this like i did.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe You Need To Install Latest Sdk
Also If You Working Net8.0 Make Sure Install Net6.0 At Least For Now I Writing This Answer, Maybe This is Very Odd ,Also Maybe Need Even Other Version Of Framework , Make Sure Check Dependecy Json To See The Version Used In Program , For Better Understaning I Will Explain In Bellow

We Have This Error In Our Company , That Was Very Odd , We Don't Know Why Our Program Can't Start On IIS, We Use Net8.0 For This Project And Make Sure Install Runtime And Sdk For Running Project , In Our System Project Run Without Problem But We Going To Production Get Error 500.30 , At Last Try To Install Net5.0 To Net8.0 , And Finally Our Problem Solved ! , That Was Very Odd Why Need Lower .Net For Running Project !, Until We Try See The Dependency Json And See Culprit in Dependency , Even If You Don't Install Any External Dependency , You Still See Net6.0 in The Dependency Json ! Why ? Because It's Use Humanizer And This Package Use Net6.0 For Running ! So If You Have Similar Problem Maybe You Have Similar Issue

Comment: Please fix your capitalization.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).