# publish .net core api on iis failed when i add reference to my project

Tags: asp.net, api, wcf, .net-core

my solution contains 5 layers and works fine in debug mode and also in publish on iis

then i added a reference to my api project
[image]

then it is working fine in debug but when i tried to publish on iis i got error

[image]

so what did i miss??

Answer (score 0):

if you publish at the same IIS the most commont issue could be an application pool. Try to create a separate application pool for this webapi

Answer (score 0):

```
HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure
```

The worker process fails. The app doesn't start.
The ASP.NET Core Module attempts to start the .NET Core CLR in-process, but it fails to start. The cause of a process startup failure can usually be determined from entries in the Application Event Log and the ASP.NET Core Module stdout log.
Here you can find more info: Troubleshoot [ASP.NET Core on Azure App Service and IIS | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/troubleshoot-azure-iis?view=aspnetcore-3.0)
This happens when there are many application pools on the same machine.
 Microsoft recommends to s**tagger the startup process** of multiple apps. Another solution would be **increase the start up limit**.
You can also try set OutOfProcess through Project->Right-click-->Properties-->Debug-->Managed model
More solutions can view [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53811569/http-error-500-30-ancm-in-process-start-failure)