# Unable to debug ASP.NET Core 3.1 apps after upgrading to VS 2022 v17.8

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, web-applications

After updating to VS 2022 v17.8, I can no longer debug my old ASP.NET Core 3.1 apps. Creating a blank ASP.NET Core 3.1 app doesn't work either.

When I try to debug the app, I get the message

> HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure

I have seen other answers about this suggesting to change to HostingModel to Out-Process but this didn't work for me.

However, if I change to .NET 6, everything works again just fine. I have verified and my PC does have the .NET Core 3.1 runtime & Hosting Bundle installed.

Comment: Look at your error logs.

Comment: @Dai there are no errors. In the output window, there's this exception "Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll"

Comment: Have you tried installing the hosting bundle? https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/3.1

Comment: Yes. As mentioned in my question, the hosting bundle is installed

Comment: No your question says you installed the runtime, not the hosting bundle.

Comment: If the app still works (e.g. running via `dotnet run`) then clearly this is VS related problem, not .NET itself problem. Try to repair your VS installation. If nothing works, reinstall.

Comment: at first I think we could try to confirm if we have the same `System.IO.FileNotFoundException` in the event view like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63061940) said. If we could find a useful exception message, we could start by this clue. If no luck, then according to your test result `Creating a blank ASP.NET Core 3.1 app doesn't work either`, I'm afraid we could repair/reinstall the VS or restart  your computer... It's hard to say we couldn't debug a newly created asp.net core 3.1 within the new VS 2022...

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/After-updating-to-VS-2022-v178-net-cor/10517164?space=41&sort=newest

Please upvote this bug.

Comment: I have provided a solution to this here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77514466/asp-net-core-3-1-projects-in-vs-2019-and-vs-2022-start-without-debugging-fails/77524485#77524485

Comment: You can have also a look at my post related to the same issue. [ASP.NET Core 3.1 projects in VS 2019 and VS 2022 - Start Without Debugging fails - HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77514466/asp-net-core-3-1-projects-in-vs-2019-and-vs-2022-start-without-debugging-fails/77524485#77524485)

Comment: After upgrading my Visual Studio Community 2022 to version 17.9.0, the problem is still here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem as reported in Developer Community of the Microsoft:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Web-app-targeting-net50-stopped-working/10515999

**Cause:**
The issue is when you have the .NET 8 SDK installed (which is installed with 17.8) and are targeting projects that are less than .NET 6 (we’ve seen reports of .NET 5 and .NET 3.1 so far but would affect anything less than 6.0).

**Workaround:**
The quickest workaround resolution for you without turning off any functionality is to do the following:

Close instances of Visual Studio
Install the .NET 7 SDK on your machine. This can live side-by-side with other SDKs. You can get the installer for Windows here: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/7.0 (using the appropriate architecture for your VS installation)

[Instructions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NEHI.png)

Comment: I experience the same issue. Its happen that after upgrading VS2023 to support .net 8 , SDK 7 was uninstalled. I had to installed manually and .net 3.1 project can now build/run vs vs2023

Answer (score 4):

Same issue is for me as well. The moment I upgraded from VS 17.7 to 17.8 my project just stopped working. Whatever I did, always the same: `HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure`. Tried re-installing everything but nothing worked. The only thing I managed to do in-order to make my project work was to upgrade VS 17.8 to 17.9 (Preview).

Note: This solution is for VS community users since that version is unable to roll-back to previous releases. Beware of the risk that this is a preview version of VS and could have other bugs.

[image: Visual studio installer]

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem in 17.8
but I have no problem in Visual Studio 2022 (version 17.7.6) on my laptop.

VS 17.7 installs sdk 7 when VS 17.8 already sdk 8. Perhaps this is the issue.

I reinstalled VS and I don't have problems.
If this option suits you, you can take the old version from here [release-history](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-history)

Answer (score 1):

Just download .NET 7 SDK and install it it will work fine

[.NET 7 SDK download link](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/sdk-7.0.404-windows-x64-installer)

Don't forget to close the visual studio first