# ANCM In-Process Start Failure, ASP.NET Core 3.1 apps after upgrading to VS 2022 v17.8

Tags: visual-studio-2022, asp.net-core-3.1

Tried Repair, Rollback, Repair, Re-install and fresh install on HYper-V nothing works.

--------Update---------

Installing VS 2019 : new project generation for 3.1 generates empty solution, and old project from 2022 are not loading.

For now - navigating to project folder in command prompt and executing "dotnet run", is keeping things going.

Publishing is working ok.

Issue is in triage for now: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/After-updating-to-VS-2022-v178-net-cor/10517164

---

Duplicate of [Unable to debug ASP.NET Core 3.1 apps after upgrading to VS 2022 v17.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77200832/unable-to-debug-asp-net-core-3-1-apps-after-upgrading-to-vs-2022-v17-8)

Stackoverflow doesn't allow any other activity than asking question @ my "reputation" so apologies for this duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is now "Under Investigation"
Till then following workaround solves the problem:
Source: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Web-app-targeting-net50-stopped-working/10515999

---

Install .NET Framework 7 SDK : https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/7.0

1. In VS top menu > Tools > Options
   [image: Tools > Options]
2. Navigate to Projects and Solutions > ASP.NET Core

[image: Projects and Solutions > ASP.NET Core]

3. Set Auto build and refresh option to None

[image]

This worked for me, hope this helps you too.