# ASP.NET Core 3.1 projects in VS 2019 and VS 2022 - Start Without Debugging fails - HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022, .net-core-3.1, .net-8.0

After upgrading VS 2022 to the latest .NET 8 I'm not able to `Start Without Debugging` ANY ASP.NET Core 3.1 project in VS 2019. The same projects (ASP.NET Core 3.1) do NOT start in VS 2022 either. Start Debugging (F5) still works.

This is the error details out of the Event Manager:

[image]

[image]

The browser (MS Edge) error is:

[image]

My VS 2019 Community installation is something like that:

```
    Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019
Version 16.11.32
VisualStudio.16.Release/16.11.32+34301.259
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.8.09037

Installed Version: Community

Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Applications 2019   00435-00000-00000-AA703
Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Applications 2019

Visual C++ 2019   00435-00000-00000-AA703
Microsoft Visual C++ 2019

ADL Tools Service Provider   1.0
This package contains services used by Data Lake tools

ASA Service Provider   1.0

ASP.NET and Web Tools 2019   16.11.116.46506
ASP.NET and Web Tools 2019

ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2019   16.11.116.46506
For additional information, visit https://www.asp.net/

Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0   16.11.116.46506
Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0

Azure Data Lake Node   1.0
This package contains the Data Lake integration nodes for Server Explorer.

Azure Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio   2.6.3000.0
Microsoft Azure Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio

Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools   16.11.116.46506
Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools

Azure Stream Analytics Tools for Visual Studio   2.6.3000.0
Microsoft Azure Stream Analytics Tools for Visual Studio

C# Tools   3.11.0-4.22108.8+d9bef045c4362fbcab27ef35daec4e95c8ff47e1
C# components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.

Common Azure Tools   1.10
Provides common services for use by Azure Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.

Cookiecutter   16.11.21196.2
Provides tools for finding, instantiating and customizing templates in cookiecutter format.

Extensibility Message Bus   1.2.6 (master@34d6af2)
Provides common messaging-based MEF services for loosely coupled Visual Studio extension components communication and integration.

Fabric.DiagnosticEvents   1.0
Fabric Diagnostic Events

GitHub.VisualStudio   2.11.106.19330
A Visual Studio Extension that brings the GitHub Flow into Visual Studio.

IntelliCode Extension   1.0
IntelliCode Visual Studio Extension Detailed Info

Microsoft Azure HDInsight Azure Node   2.6.3000.0
HDInsight Node under Azure Node

Microsoft Azure Hive Query Language Service   2.6.3000.0
Language service for Hive query

Microsoft Azure Service Fabric Tools for Visual Studio   16.10
Microsoft Azure Service Fabric Tools for Visual Studio

Microsoft Azure Stream Analytics Language Service   2.6.3000.0
Language service for Azure Stream Analytics

Microsoft Azure Stream Analytics Node   1.0
Azure Stream Analytics Node under Azure Node

Microsoft Azure Tools for Visual Studio   2.9
Support for Azure Cloud Services projects

Microsoft Continuous Delivery Tools for Visual Studio   0.4
Simplifying the configuration of Azure DevOps pipelines from within the Visual Studio IDE.

Microsoft JVM Debugger   1.0
Provides support for connecting the Visual Studio debugger to JDWP compatible Java Virtual Machines

Microsoft Library Manager   2.1.126+g11d4cf0d0c.RR
Install client-side libraries easily to any web project

Microsoft MI-Based Debugger   1.0
Provides support for connecting Visual Studio to MI compatible debuggers

Microsoft Visual C++ Wizards   1.0
Microsoft Visual C++ Wizards

Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Containers   1.2
Develop, run, validate your ASP.NET Core applications in the target environment. F5 your application directly into a container with debugging, or CTRL + F5 to edit & refresh your app without having to rebuild the container.

Microsoft Visual Studio VC Package   1.0
Microsoft Visual Studio VC Package

Mono Debugging for Visual Studio   16.10.15 (552afdf)
Support for debugging Mono processes with Visual Studio.

Node.js Tools   1.5.30526.3 Commit Hash:c09c81113bcbc86d57943fcdd67e82434263d61d
Adds support for developing and debugging Node.js apps in Visual Studio

NuGet Package Manager   5.11.4
NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio. For more information about NuGet, visit https://docs.nuget.org/

Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio   16.0.31424.03
Microsoft Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio

ProjectServicesPackage Extension   1.0
ProjectServicesPackage Visual Studio Extension Detailed Info

Python   16.11.21196.2
Provides IntelliSense, projects, templates, debugging, interactive windows, and other support for Python developers.

Python - Conda support   16.11.21196.2
Conda support for Python projects.

Python - Django support   16.11.21196.2
Provides templates and integration for the Django web framework.

Python - Profiling support   16.11.21196.2
Profiling support for Python projects.

Razor (ASP.NET Core)   16.1.0.2122504+13c05c96ea6bdbe550bd88b0bf6cdddf8cde1725
Provides languages services for ASP.NET Core Razor.

SQL Server Data Tools   16.0.62205.05200
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools

Test Adapter for Boost.Test   1.0
Enables Visual Studio's testing tools with unit tests written for Boost.Test.  The use terms and Third Party Notices are available in the extension installation directory.

Test Adapter for Google Test   1.0
Enables Visual Studio's testing tools with unit tests written for Google Test.  The use terms and Third Party Notices are available in the extension installation directory.

ToolWindowHostedEditor   1.0
Hosting json editor into a tool window

TypeScript Tools   16.0.30526.2002
TypeScript Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio

Visual Basic Tools   3.11.0-4.22108.8+d9bef045c4362fbcab27ef35daec4e95c8ff47e1
Visual Basic components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.

Visual F# Tools   16.11.0-beta.21514.6+b6c2c4f53ea3a08fa603ea93d6d2f808a62a21d1
Microsoft Visual F# Tools

Visual Studio Code Debug Adapter Host Package   1.0
Interop layer for hosting Visual Studio Code debug adapters in Visual Studio

Visual Studio Container Tools Extensions   1.0
View, manage, and diagnose containers within Visual Studio.

Visual Studio Tools for CMake   1.0
Visual Studio Tools for CMake

Visual Studio Tools for Containers   1.0
Visual Studio Tools for Containers

Visual Studio Tools for Kubernetes   1.0
Visual Studio Tools for Kubernetes

VisualStudio.DeviceLog   1.0
Information about my package

VisualStudio.Foo   1.0
Information about my package

VisualStudio.Mac   1.0
Mac Extension for Visual Studio

Workflow Manager Tools 1.0   1.0
This package contains the necessary Visual Studio integration components for Workflow Manager.

Xamarin   16.11.000.204 (d16-11@8671d2f)
Visual Studio extension to enable development for Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android.

Xamarin Designer   16.11.0.47 (remotes/origin/d16-11@e0d612363)
Visual Studio extension to enable Xamarin Designer tools in Visual Studio.

Xamarin Templates   16.10.5 (355b57a)
Templates for building iOS, Android, and Windows apps with Xamarin and Xamarin.Forms.

Xamarin.Android SDK   12.0.0.3 (d16-11/f0e3c2d)
Xamarin.Android Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support.
    Mono: c633fe9
    Java.Interop: xamarin/java.interop/d16-11@476bb5b
    ProGuard: Guardsquare/proguard/v7.0.1@912d149
    SQLite: xamarin/sqlite/3.35.4@85460d3
    Xamarin.Android Tools: xamarin/xamarin-android-tools/d16-11@87af37b


Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac SDK   15.2.0.17 (738fde344)
Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support.
```

My VS 2022 Community installation is something like that:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022
Version 17.8.0
VisualStudio.17.Release/17.8.0+34309.116
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.8.09037

Installed Version: Community

Visual C++ 2022   00482-90000-00000-AA748
Microsoft Visual C++ 2022

ADL Tools Service Provider   1.0
This package contains services used by Data Lake tools

ASA Service Provider   1.0

ASP.NET and Web Tools   17.8.352.38654
ASP.NET and Web Tools

Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0   17.8.352.38654
Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0

Azure Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio   2.6.5000.0
Microsoft Azure Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio

Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools   17.8.352.38654
Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools

Azure Stream Analytics Tools for Visual Studio   2.6.5000.0
Microsoft Azure Stream Analytics Tools for Visual Studio

Bundler & Minifier   2.9.9
Adds support for bundling and minifying JavaScript, CSS and HTML files in any project.

C# Tools   4.8.0-7.23558.1+e091728607ca0fc9efca55ccfb3e59259c6b5a0a
C# components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.

Common Azure Tools   1.10
Provides common services for use by Azure Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.

Cookiecutter   17.0.23262.1
Provides tools for finding, instantiating and customizing templates in cookiecutter format.

Extensibility Message Bus   1.4.39 (main@e8108eb)
Provides common messaging-based MEF services for loosely coupled Visual Studio extension components communication and integration.

Microsoft Azure Hive Query Language Service   2.6.5000.0
Language service for Hive query

Microsoft Azure Stream Analytics Language Service   2.6.5000.0
Language service for Azure Stream Analytics

Microsoft Azure Tools for Visual Studio   2.9
Support for Azure Cloud Services projects

Microsoft JVM Debugger   1.0
Provides support for connecting the Visual Studio debugger to JDWP compatible Java Virtual Machines

Mono Debugging for Visual Studio   17.8.17 (957fbed)
Support for debugging Mono processes with Visual Studio.

NuGet Package Manager   6.8.0
NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio. For more information about NuGet, visit https://docs.nuget.org/

Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio   17.6.34024.01
Microsoft Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio

Python - Django support   17.0.23262.1
Provides templates and integration for the Django web framework.

Python - Profiling support   17.0.23262.1
Profiling support for Python projects.

Python - VC Project Support   17.0.23055.1
Provides support for launching C++ projects with Python debugging enabled.

Python with Pylance   17.0.23262.1
Provides IntelliSense, projects, templates, debugging, interactive windows, and other support for Python developers.

Razor (ASP.NET Core)   17.8.3.2353105+f0a326f3e15b2370371693a76fd379635387c74d
Provides languages services for ASP.NET Core Razor.

SQL Server Data Tools   17.8.119.0
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools

ToolWindowHostedEditor   1.0
Hosting json editor into a tool window

TypeScript Tools   17.0.20920.2001
TypeScript Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio

Visual Basic Tools   4.8.0-7.23558.1+e091728607ca0fc9efca55ccfb3e59259c6b5a0a
Visual Basic components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.

Visual F# Tools   17.8.0-beta.23475.2+10f956e631a1efc0f7f5e49c626c494cd32b1f50
Microsoft Visual F# Tools

Visual Studio IntelliCode   2.2
AI-assisted development for Visual Studio.

VisualStudio.DeviceLog   1.0
Information about my package

VisualStudio.Mac   1.0
Mac Extension for Visual Studio

VSPackage Extension   1.0
VSPackage Visual Studio Extension Detailed Info

Workflow Manager Tools 1.0   1.0
This package contains the necessary Visual Studio integration components for Workflow Manager.

Xamarin   17.8.0.155 (d17-8@7042beb)
Visual Studio extension to enable development for Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android.

Xamarin Designer   17.8.3.6 (remotes/origin/d17-8@eccf46a291)
Visual Studio extension to enable Xamarin Designer tools in Visual Studio.

Xamarin Templates   17.8.16 (830b56a)
Templates for building iOS, Android, and Windows apps with Xamarin and Xamarin.Forms.

Xamarin.Android SDK   13.2.2.0 (d17-5/45b0e14)
Xamarin.Android Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support.
    Mono: d9a6e87
    Java.Interop: xamarin/java.interop/d17-5@149d70fe
    SQLite: xamarin/sqlite/3.40.1@68c69d8
    Xamarin.Android Tools: xamarin/xamarin-android-tools/d17-5@ca1552d


Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac SDK   16.4.0.23 (9defd91b3)
Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support.
```

I've also created in VS 2019 a BRAND NEW ASP.NET Core 3.1 project, form the available template. Start Without Debugging does NOT work as well.

In the `web.config` file I've enabled `stdoutLogEnabled`.

```
    <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\TEST_WebApplication.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess">
        <handlerSettings>
          <handlerSetting name="debugFile" value=".\logs\aspnetcore-debug.log" />
          <handlerSetting name="debugLevel" value="FILE,TRACE" />
        </handlerSettings>
      </aspNetCore>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
```

The log file was:

```
    [2023-11-19T08:29:18.793Z, PID: 24964] [aspnetcorev2.dll] Initializing logs for 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\Asp.Net Core Module\V2\aspnetcorev2.dll'. Process Id: 24964. File Version: 17.0.22116.0. Description: IIS ASP.NET Core Module V2. Commit: bd6dbc1f547a28d02fadfe082936e77e56b61a4e.
[2023-11-19T08:29:18.800Z, PID: 24964] [aspnetcorev2.dll] Resolving hostfxr parameters for application: 'C:\Users\MARCO\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Projects\TEST_WebApplication\TEST_WebApplication\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\TEST_WebApplication.exe' arguments: '.\TEST_WebApplication.dll' path: 'C:\Users\MARCO\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Projects\TEST_WebApplication\TEST_WebApplication\'
[2023-11-19T08:29:18.803Z, PID: 24964] [aspnetcorev2.dll] Known dotnet.exe location: ''
[2023-11-19T08:29:18.805Z, PID: 24964] [aspnetcorev2.dll] Process path 'C:\Users\MARCO\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Projects\TEST_WebApplication\TEST_WebApplication\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\TEST_WebApplication.exe' is not dotnet, treating application as standalone or portable with bootstrapper
[2023-11-19T08:29:18.810Z, PID: 24964] [aspnetcorev2.dll] Checking application.dll at 'C:\Users\MARCO\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Projects\TEST_WebApplication\TEST_WebApplication\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\TEST_WebApplication.dll'
[2023-11-19T08:29:18.813Z, PID: 24964] [aspnetcorev2.dll] Checking hostfxr.dll at 'C:\Users\MARCO\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Projects\TEST_WebApplication\TEST_WebApplication\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\hostfxr.dll'
[2023-11-19T08:29:18.817Z, PID: 24964] [aspnetcorev2.dll] hostfxr.dll not found at 'C:\Users\MARCO\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Projects\TEST_WebApplication\TEST_WebApplication\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\hostfxr.dll', treating application as portable with launcher
[2023-11-19T08:29:18.819Z, PID: 24964] [aspnetcorev2.dll] Resolving absolute path to dotnet.exe from 'dotnet'
[2023-11-19T08:29:18.822Z, PID: 24964] [aspnetcorev2.dll] Invoking where.exe to find dotnet.exe
[2023-11-19T08:29:19.198Z, PID: 24964] [aspnetcorev2.dll] where.exe invocation returned: 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe
'
[2023-11-19T08:29:19.205Z, PID: 24964] [aspnetcorev2.dll] Current process bitness type detected as isX64=1
[2023-11-19T08:29:19.207Z, PID: 24964] [aspnetcorev2.dll] Processing entry 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe'
[2023-11-19T08:29:19.209Z, PID: 24964] [aspnetcorev2.dll] Binary type 6
[2023-11-19T08:29:19.212Z, PID: 24964] [aspnetcorev2.dll] Found dotnet.exe via where.exe invocation at 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe'
[2023-11-19T08:29:19.214Z, PID: 24964] [aspnetcorev2.dll] hostfxr.dotnet_root: 'C:\Program Files\dotnet'
[2023-11-19T08:29:19.216Z, PID: 24964] [aspnetcorev2.dll] hostfxr.assembly_path: 'C:\Users\MARCO\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Projects\TEST_WebApplication\TEST_WebApplication\'
[2023-11-19T08:29:19.219Z, PID: 24964] [aspnetcorev2.dll] Parsed hostfxr options: dotnet location: 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe' hostfxr path: 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\host\fxr\8.0.0\hostfxr.dll' arguments:
[2023-11-19T08:29:19.222Z, PID: 24964] [aspnetcorev2.dll] Argument[0] = 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe'
[2023-11-19T08:29:19.223Z, PID: 24964] [aspnetcorev2.dll] Argument[1] = 'C:\Users\MARCO\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Projects\TEST_WebApplication\TEST_WebApplication\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\TEST_WebApplication.dll'
[2023-11-19T08:29:19.224Z, PID: 24964] [aspnetcorev2.dll] Argument[2] = '.\TEST_WebApplication.dll'
[2023-11-19T08:29:19.226Z, PID: 24964] [aspnetcorev2.dll] Loading hostfxr from location C:\Program Files\dotnet\host\fxr\8.0.0\hostfxr.dll
[2023-11-19T08:29:19.329Z, PID: 24964] [aspnetcorev2.dll] Canceling standard stream pipe reader
[2023-11-19T08:29:19.335Z, PID: 24964] [aspnetcorev2.dll] Loading request handler:  'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.32\aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll'
[2023-11-19T08:29:19.339Z, PID: 24964] [aspnetcorev2.dll] Creating handler application

    [aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Initializing logs for 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.32\aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll'. Process Id: 24964.. File Version: 13.1.22321.32. Description: IIS ASP.NET Core Module V2 Request Handler. Commit: 3eeb12e106b9e913c3a4dec1a7d16da7b74149eb.
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Waiting for initialization
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Starting in-process worker thread
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Resolving hostfxr parameters for application: 'C:\Users\MARCO\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Projects\TEST_WebApplication\TEST_WebApplication\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\TEST_WebApplication.exe' arguments: '.\TEST_WebApplication.dll' path: 'C:\Users\MARCO\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Projects\TEST_WebApplication\TEST_WebApplication\'
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Known dotnet.exe location: 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe'
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Process path 'C:\Users\MARCO\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Projects\TEST_WebApplication\TEST_WebApplication\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\TEST_WebApplication.exe' is not dotnet, treating application as standalone or portable with bootstrapper
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Checking application.dll at 'C:\Users\MARCO\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Projects\TEST_WebApplication\TEST_WebApplication\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\TEST_WebApplication.dll'
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Checking hostfxr.dll at 'C:\Users\MARCO\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Projects\TEST_WebApplication\TEST_WebApplication\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\hostfxr.dll'
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] hostfxr.dll found app local at 'C:\Users\MARCO\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Projects\TEST_WebApplication\TEST_WebApplication\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\hostfxr.dll', treating application as portable with launcher
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Resolving absolute path to hostfxr.dll from 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe'
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] hostfxr.dll located at 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\host\fxr\8.0.0\hostfxr.dll'
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Parsed hostfxr options: dotnet location: 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe' hostfxr path: 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\host\fxr\8.0.0\hostfxr.dll' arguments:
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Argument[0] = 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe'
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Argument[1] = 'C:\Users\MARCO\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Projects\TEST_WebApplication\TEST_WebApplication\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\TEST_WebApplication.dll'
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Argument[2] = '.\TEST_WebApplication.dll'
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Setting environment variable ASPNETCORE_IIS_HTTPAUTH=anonymous;
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Setting environment variable ASPNETCORE_IIS_PHYSICAL_PATH=C:\Users\MARCO\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Projects\TEST_WebApplication\TEST_WebApplication\
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Loading hostfxr from location C:\Program Files\dotnet\host\fxr\8.0.0\hostfxr.dll
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Initial Dll directory: 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express', current directory: 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express'
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Setting current directory to C:\Users\MARCO\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Projects\TEST_WebApplication\TEST_WebApplication\
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Managed threw an exception -532462766
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Starting shutdown sequence 1
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Clr thread wait ended: clrThreadExited: 1
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Canceling standard stream pipe reader
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Event Log: 'Application '/LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT' with physical root 'C:\Users\MARCO\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Projects\TEST_WebApplication\TEST_WebApplication\' hit unexpected managed exception, exception code = '0xe0434352'. Please check the stderr logs for more information.' 
End Event Log Message.
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Stopping in-process worker thread
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Stopping CLR
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Event Log: 'Application '/LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT' with physical root 'C:\Users\MARCO\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Projects\TEST_WebApplication\TEST_WebApplication\' failed to load coreclr. Exception message:
CLR worker thread exited prematurely' 
End Event Log Message.
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] InvalidOperationException 'CLR worker thread exited prematurely' caught at D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Servers\IIS\AspNetCoreModuleV2\InProcessRequestHandler\inprocessapplication.cpp:420 
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Failed HRESULT returned: 0x8007023e at D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Servers\IIS\AspNetCoreModuleV2\InProcessRequestHandler\dllmain.cpp:131 
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Starting app_offline monitoring in application 'C:\Users\MARCO\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Projects\TEST_WebApplication\TEST_WebApplication\'
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Starting file watcher thread
```

I've also tried to set the used SDK version in the `global.json` file:

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "3.1.426",
    "rollForward": "disable"
  }
}
```

but it did not help.

In the `Program.cs` file I have also declared to use IIS like that:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder
                .UseIISIntegration()
                .UseIIS()
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
```

My last try was to start the project from the command line, with `dotnet run`.
In this case it works, the website can be reached under `https://localhost:5001/` and not under the port indicated in the project properties.

```
dotnet --info output is:

    C:\Users\MARCO>dotnet --info
.NET SDK:
 Version:           8.0.100
 Commit:            57efcf1350
 Workload version:  8.0.100-manifests.8d38d0cc

Laufzeitumgebung:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.19045
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.100\

Installierte .NET-Workloads:
 Workload version: 8.0.100-manifests.8d38d0cc
 [android]
   Installationsquelle: VS 17.8.34309.116
   Manifestversion:    34.0.43/8.0.100
   Manifestpfad:       C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk-manifests\8.0.100\microsoft.net.sdk.android\34.0.43\WorkloadManifest.json
   Installationstyp:              Msi

 [wasm-tools]
   Installationsquelle: VS 17.8.34309.116
   Manifestversion:    8.0.0/8.0.100
   Manifestpfad:       C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk-manifests\8.0.100\microsoft.net.workload.mono.toolchain.current\8.0.0\WorkloadManifest.json
   Installationstyp:              Msi

 [ios]
   Installationsquelle: VS 17.8.34309.116
   Manifestversion:    17.0.8478/8.0.100
   Manifestpfad:       C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk-manifests\8.0.100\microsoft.net.sdk.ios\17.0.8478\WorkloadManifest.json
   Installationstyp:              Msi

 [maui-windows]
   Installationsquelle: VS 17.8.34309.116
   Manifestversion:    8.0.3/8.0.100
   Manifestpfad:       C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk-manifests\8.0.100\microsoft.net.sdk.maui\8.0.3\WorkloadManifest.json
   Installationstyp:              Msi

 [maccatalyst]
   Installationsquelle: VS 17.8.34309.116
   Manifestversion:    17.0.8478/8.0.100
   Manifestpfad:       C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk-manifests\8.0.100\microsoft.net.sdk.maccatalyst\17.0.8478\WorkloadManifest.json
   Installationstyp:              Msi


Host:
  Version:      8.0.0
  Architecture: x64
  Commit:       5535e31a71

.NET SDKs installed:
  1.0.0-preview2-003131 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  1.0.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  1.1.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  1.1.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.0.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.0.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.100 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.617 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.700 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.818 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.2.204 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.2.300 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.2.401 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.2.402 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  3.1.426 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  5.0.103 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  5.0.104 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  5.0.202 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  5.0.214 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  5.0.302 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  5.0.303 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  5.0.402 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  5.0.408 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  5.0.416 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  8.0.100 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem and after many hours have found a solution.

Go to a command prompt and type

dotnet --list-sdks

Even though my dotnet --info was returning all the API's and SDK's the above command only showed 6.0.417 and 8.0.100.

Installing the 3.1 sdk again didn't solve the problem.  In the end I had to go to https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/3.1 and download the x64 binary.  Then I took the 3.1.426 folder from the binary zip file and put it in c:\program files\dotnet\sdk

After doing this debug works again with VS2022 and dotnet core 3.1 projects.

Comment: Hello uksid, my problem is not debugging, but rather "Start Without Debugging". If I F5-start a project, it worls fine. I get the error above when I try to "Start Without Debugging"

Comment: A similar problem has been reported in another SO thread [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77200832/unable-to-debug-asp-net-core-3-1-apps-after-upgrading-to-vs-2022-v17-8?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Let's then wait for 17.9

Comment: VS 17.9.0 is here, but it does not solve the problem. No way to start without debugging my ASP.NET Core 3.1 projects, both in VS 2019 and in VS 2022