# Why am I getting: Cannot instantiate implementation type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionDescriptorCollectionProvider'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm charged with migrating my company's website from ASP.NET Core 2.1 to 2.2 and have been following this guide: [Migrate from ASP.NET Core 2.1 to 2.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/21-to-22?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio)

I've downloaded the necessary SDK and updated the TargetFramework and all the PakageReferences in the project file. Compiles fine but at runtime I'm getting this error in the console: ***System.ArgumentException: Cannot instantiate implementation type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionDescriptorCollectionProvider' for service type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider'.***

I found these lines in Startup.cs:

```
   // HttpContext
   services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
   services.AddSingleton<IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider, ActionDescriptorCollectionProvider>();
   services.AddSingleton<ConcurrentQueue<HttpContext>, ConcurrentQueue<HttpContext>>();
   services.AddSingleton<INetDocTokenService, NetDocTokenService>();
```

If I comment out the second line the above error is avoided but the app then crashes at launch with an unhandled exception. Visual Studio shows this message: *"Your app has entered a break state, but there is no code to show because all threads were executing external code (typically system or framework code)."*

Can anyone tell me how to resolve this error?

Comment: Check your DI services..... And also this could help 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42987892/why-am-i-getting-the-error-cannot-instantiate-implementation-type-for-my-gener

Comment: asp.net core 2.x is [not supported](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-2-1-will-reach-end-of-support-on-august-21-2021/) now...